# Save keywords / meta title in Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I've recently started tampering with Mezzanine and I am trying to add 2 new fields to the Blog Post admin -- keywords, and meta title.

I did it by editing my admin.py file and adding the following:

```
from mezzanine.blog.admin import BlogPostAdmin
from mezzanine.generic.models import Keyword, AssignedKeyword
BlogPostAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].extend(["keywords"])
BlogPostAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].extend(["_meta_title"])

admin.site.register(Keyword)
admin.site.register(AssignedKeyword)
```

I see the fields in the blog post manager, but when I edit them specific to a blog post, they don't save to that post. However, if I am adding keywords, the keywords get saved to the overall site keywords (`generic_keyword` table).

Is there any way to make them also update the blog post such that _meta_title and keywords_string gets updated in `blog_blogpost`? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: After looking into this further, it doesn't seem that I need to do anything to get the "Meta Data" section to be expandable. However, in my copy, it cannot be expanded. Is there any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is a bit incomplete, and will be misleading for anyone who comes across the same problem.

My guess is that at some point you copied the admin's base_site.html template into your project, from an older version of Mezzanine. You've then later upgraded to a newer version of Mezzanine, which refers to an upgraded version of chosen - you can see the commit from 3 months ago here where that occurred here: https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/commit/f4e33282eaac44ef8ebbadb9b0157d910c67973a

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences this issue, check your javascript console. In my case, for whatever reason, the Admin section was trying to load `mezzanine/chosen/chosen-0.9.12.jquery.js` which doesn't exist. I edited blog/templates/admin/base_site.html and updated it to `mezzanine/chosen/chosen.jquery.js` and the Meta Data section became expandable/collapsible again.